# Drupal no www. linking

Tags: drupal, hyperlink

how can I disable automatically converting WWW.SOMETHING into a link in Drupal?

I just want to display URL , don't create a like.

This must be done per page, as some of the pages need to have it works as links.

so is there a special TAG or something to tell DRUPAL not to convert it to linkable text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auto conversion of URLs into links is handled by the "*input format*" specified for the node.

To avoid this happening for a specific node, create a new input format where the **Url Filter** is not enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the input format. Create one that matches your default and remove the URL filter (which is responsible for this). Then you can select it as input format for one node only, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The input format is probably the best solution, but a quick and dirty trick I have used on the rare occasion I needed to thwart auto-linking was to break up the non-url with formatting tags.

For example, if Drupal was converting `www.foobar` to a link, I would code the text as follows:

`<i>www</i>.foobar`

Not pretty, but I does the job if you are in a pinch.